# Redirect all accessible URL's to only one specific subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have my working worpress domains, subdomain and alias working normally and locate at root web server "**www/**".

```
htpps://domain.com
htpps://domain.net
htpps://en.domain.net
```

Later I decide to install a support web application in same server in folder "**www/support/**".

Setting this support app I needed to set one domain or subdomain, and I set "**support.domain.com**".

After last step I realise that all the following URL's could access to the support app:

```
htpps://domain.com/support
htpps://domain.net/support
htpps://en.domain.net/support

htpps://support.domain.com/support
htpps://support.domain.net/support
```

Since this support app doesn't work correctly with differents domains or subdomains from the main one that was set initially ( that was: "**support.domain.com**" ), I'm trying to redirect all to one unique subdomain: "**support.domain.com**".

The file "**.htaccess**" locate in support app folder ("**www/support/.htaccess**") still empty, all rewrite rules I try didn't worked, due my low knowledge.

- How could I redirect all accessible URL's to only one "**support.domain.com**"?

or

- Block all access to this folder "**www/support/index.php**" that are not "**support.domain.com**"?

I found and try lots of similar questions but none work correctly or give too many redirections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in support.htaccess, you can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.+ http://support.domain.com/ [L]
```

Comment: I just add this lines in my empty **support/.htaccess** and nothings changes. No redirection done, in none of the URL's.

Answer (score 0):

After several time pass over, I finally locate the problem, double quotes was **“** instead of **"**

This small details was creating problem in every .**htaccess** file in my host, after this correction all working correctly and it reach **support/.htaccess** now.